# How to store user information and allow user to edit, manage and delete it

Tags: wordpress

I am currently working on a website to manage rental properties.  I would like users to be able to go to a page, enter information for a particular property (address, owner, etc.) and "submit" that information.  The problem I am having is I cannot find a good way to manage the information, as well as give users the ability to delete that information at will.  I would like this all done on the front end as I can't think of a good solution without significant SQL injection concerns.  Ideally I would like all the information displayed with a small (x) next to each row.

I apologize that may sound very convoluted and vague.

1. User submits information about zero to many of his rental properties.
2. User goes to another page (or same page) and can view and manage his properties
3. User sells property; Deletes one or more of his properties

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [custom post types](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/) for properties (you'd have a custom post type called Property) and [meta data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Meta_Data_Section) for storing any arbitrary info related to each property. That's a rough outline of how I would structure things for a project like this.

You'll need to do a fair bit of coding for the front-end forms, validation, storing/updating/listing data. The good news is that WordPress will provide lots of nice things for you out of the box, like authentication/authorization, user management, a great mechanism for listing posts (a.k.a. your properties) and categorizing them.